# C# / ASP.NET Core Web API : how to pass a list parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to pass a list parameter to an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API.

Here is my endpoint:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class InvoiceController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public InvoiceController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public List<CustomerInvoice> Post(string[] CustomerNumbers, DateTime OrderDateFrom, DateTime OrderDateTo)
    {
    }
}
```

Sending json post request fails with this error:

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.String[]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.

and here is the request:

```
{
    "CustomerNumbers": ["test"],
    "OrderDateFrom": "2021-01-01",
    "OrderDateTo": "2021-11-02"
}
```

Instead of using a string array, I also tried `List<string>`. I got the same error.

Any idea why the framework does not understand how to receive a list?

Comment: What's the JSON value look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a class and receive JSON with this class. This may solve your problem.

```
public class ClassExample
{
    public List<string> CustomerNumbers { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDateTo { get; set; }
}



[HttpPost]
public List<CustomerInvoice> Post(ClassExample requestParameter)
{
}
```

Comment: Great. This does work. Thanks. My comment documentations do not appear in swagger with this approach. Do you know if there is a documentation on this?